# PHP max upload file = 300M

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to configure my website to allow max upload size on php.ini = 300M?
I can't run a test for this because i'm working on live server. somebody?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem than even if you upgrade that amount of size on the php.ini configuration file, or also if you need the .htaccess, it depends on the server, i always ask people that own the server to do it on apache first, then I do it on my php.ini, I know that you can upgrade the size of the upload more than 300MB, just look at the configurations of the live server

Comment: FYI : Xeon quadcore, with 12G of RAM... what do you think?